# Difference between react hooks returning from useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to migrate my code from class to function in react

I was trying to understand the difference between these two react hooks

```
export const useEffectExceptOnMount = (effect: () => void, dependencies: Array<any>) => {
  const mounted = useRef(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (mounted.current) {
      effect()
      return
    } else {
      mounted.current = true
    }
  }, dependencies)

  // Reset on unmount for the next mount.
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      mounted.current = false
    }
  }, [])
}
```

And

```
export const useEffectExceptOnMount = (effect: () => void, dependencies: Array<any>) => {
  const mounted = useRef(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (mounted.current) {
      return () => {
       effect()
      }
    } else {
      mounted.current = true
    }
  }, dependencies)

  // Reset on unmount for the next mount.
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      mounted.current = false
    }
  }, [])
}
```

(notice how `effect()` is called) here..

When they are used like this in a component like this?

```
  useEffectExceptOnMount(() => {
    callUpdateApi()
  }, [auth, person])
```

Comment: The second variation seems to call the effect on unmount, not on mount. You may be looking for https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useUpdateEffect.md as a premade implementation of this.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in the first version `effect` is run every time the `dependencies` are changed and consequently the `useEffect` runs.

In the second one though the `effect` is run during "effect clean up". Meaning it runs when new effect comes in and react cleans up previous effect. To see better use both at the same time:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

// custom hook to refer previous state
export const useEffectExceptOnMountA = (effect, dependencies) => {
  const mounted = useRef(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (mounted.current) {
      return () => {
        effect();
      };
    } else {
      mounted.current = true;
    }
  }, dependencies);

  // Reset on unmount for the next mount.
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      mounted.current = false;
    };
  }, []);
};

export const useEffectExceptOnMountB = (effect, dependencies) => {
  const mounted = useRef(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (mounted.current) {
      effect();
      return;
    } else {
      mounted.current = true;
    }
  }, dependencies);

  // Reset on unmount for the next mount.
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      mounted.current = false;
    };
  }, []);
};


export default function Parent() {
  let [s, set] = useState(0);
  useEffectExceptOnMountA(() => {
    console.log("A");
  }, [s]);

  useEffectExceptOnMountB(() => {
    console.log("B");
  }, [s]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => set((s) => s + 1)}>Go</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here once the `Parent` is rendered if you click on `Go` button, first time you see:

```
B
```

But if you click for the second time then the console looks like:

```
B  <== from previous click
A
B
```

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-jang-80gp6) and the documentation [Effects with Cleanup](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup)